# Creating partition with trigger

Tags: mysql, partitioning, mysql-5.6

Is it possible to automate the new partition creation process for an existing table using triggers in Mysql 5.6?

I have two tables Table A and Table B. I need to make list partition Table B based on column ID. If a new column inserted in Table A i need to automate the process for creating partition in Table B with the new ID.

```
**Table A            Table B
ID                 ID 
1                  1
2                  2
3**
```

Now i need to automate the process of creating partition for Id value 3 in Table B so that it will not throw error while inserting Record in Table B.

Comment: Generally, DDL statements are not allowed in Triggers.

Comment: Why do you have `BY LIST`?  Do you have a test that shows that it is faster or otherwise better than non-partitioning?

Comment: @Rick James no i did not test yet and i want to test the performance with list partition and no partition

Answer (score 0):

One can create a stored procedure to create partition at runtime but by calling the stored procedure and running dynamicSQL inside it to create new partitions with custom names.

You can understand this by following example where we are creating partition over sales table dynamically based on date( which is quite common task to have data day wise)

```
Let the table definition :


CREATE TABLE Sales (
customer_id int NOT NULL,
customer_name varchar(40),
store_id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
bill_number int NOT NULL,
bill_date date PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
amount decimal(8, 2) NOT NULL
 )




PARTITION BY RANGE (YEAR(bill_date)) (  // some static partition 
   PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2016),
   PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2017),
   PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2018),
   PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2020)
   );



//Stored Procedure to create partition:

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE AddPartitionToTable( IN newPartitionValue DATE)

BEGIN




 -- Create the dynamic SQL statement, using a prepared statement for security
SET @dynamicSQL := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE Sales', ' ADD PARTITION (PARTITION p', DATE_FORMAT(newPartitionValue, '%Y%m%d'), ' VALUES LESS THAN (Year(''', newPartitionValue, ''')))');




PREPARE stmt FROM @dynamicSQL;



 EXECUTE stmt;



DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //
```

DELIMITER ;